# Community-bot keeps bumping

Tags: discussion

The Community moderator bot occasionally bumps old questions. This is really helpful. But in the past two months or so as I've answered those old questions, the OP has never come back to accept or upvote. Checking in on these a few weeks later, the OP hasn't even logged back in.

In some cases (such as https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/magento-sales-report-how-to)  I've seen that the OP has has been idle for > 2 months.

Is there a way that we can control the behavior of the Community Modbot to prevent it from bumping posts that are:

- Newer than 60 days
- The OP has been seen < 30 days ago
- Has < 200 views

Some questions just aren't answerable; no need to keep bumping them. Unfortunately our power user activity has dropped lately and it seems like we can't get the 5 votes needed to close/flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still a question might be of value, even the OP did not come back. So I do not see a point in not bumping them, if the OP is not active on the site anymore (and even if the OP is not active, he still might get email notifications upon your answers - but this is sure not granted)

All those questions count to our "unanswered statistics" - so it is fine to bump them.

If the questions are not answerable / too localized / such things, just use the close votes or flag them to get some mod attention on them.

Comment: Close votes aren't gaining traction right now IMHO, symptom of another problem. I understand what you mean; but answering questions takes a *lot* of time and without feedback from the OP how do we know if we've answered it?

Comment: close + flag :-) And if the question is not specific enough to see if it is answered, a down vote + comment for improvement might be fine. If the OP does not respond to the comment, you know s/he is not interested any more.